# Cauchy integral formula in complex analysis

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, self-learning

Assume $g$ be an entire function. And $\exists \ n\gt 0 \:and\ n\in \Bbb Z $ and also $\exists N \: and\ M \in \Bbb R$ s.t. $\forall z \in \Bbb C , \ \ \vert z\vert \ge M\ \  \: and\ \ \ \vert g(z)\vert \le N\vert z\vert^n $.

By using *Cauchy Integral Formula*, I want to show $g$ to be polynomial of degree at most $n$.

---

**Cauchy Integral Formula**

I posted a link which stated C-I formula as above. But I cannot apply this to show that the question. Please help me. Thanks a lot:)

[cauchy integral formula - lecture notes](http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/wchen/lnicafolder/ica06.pdf)

---

This is just self-learning. I have an exam. And I need to learn such a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Cauchy integral formula,

$g(z) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{C_r} \frac{g(\eta)}{\eta -z} d\eta$ where $C_r$ is the circle of radius $r$ centered at $z$.  Then, by diffentiating both sides,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           it is easy to see that $g^n(z) = \frac{n!}{2 \pi i} \int_{C_r} \frac{g(\eta)}{(\eta -z)^{n+1}} d\eta$.

So that $|g^n(z)| \leq \frac {n!}{2 \pi} 2 \pi r \times \sup_{ |\eta - z| =r} \frac{|g(\eta)|}{ r^{n+1}} \leq n!r \times \frac{Nr^n}{r^{n+1}} = n!N$ for all $|z| > M$.  Moreover, the set $\{z: |z| \leq M\}$ is compact so $g^n$ is bounded on that set as well since $g^n$ is analytic and hence continuous there.

So we have shown that the entire function $g^n$ is bounded on the entire complex plane.
Hence, $g^n$ is constant $\implies g$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq n$.

Comment: Thank you Mustafa! In fact, I dont understand something. How can we say that $g^n$ be constant because it is bounded on the entire complex plane? And why this implies g is polynomial of degree $\le n$. Please can you be more clear for the last statement?

Comment: @B11b this stands due to the Liouville's theorem.

Comment: Okay I Will look at the theorem. Well, I want you to do last thing. If you have time, can you look at the question? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603025/to-alternatively-prove-the-theorem-by-proving-that-gn1z-0-0-foral?noredirect=1#comment1270341_603025 JonathanY solved it. But S/he cannot complete the last part of the question. Can you help me? And can you complete this?

Comment: For the last part, to show that $g^n = C \implies g$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$, just use power series.

Answer (score 1):

I'll write that $f$ insted of $g$ (i like more $f$:P) and $s$ instead of $n$.

Let $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_nz^n$,$z\in \Bbb C$.Then $$c_n=\frac {f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$$.

Let $r>0$. We have that for $w\in C(0,r)$, $|f(w)|\leq N|w|^s=Nr^s$. Hence from Cauchy's inequialities we have $$|c_n|=\frac {f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\leq \frac {Nr^s}{r^n}=>|c_n|\leq \frac {N}{r^{n-s}}$$.

Now take a $n>s$ (constant). Then $$|c_n|\leq \frac {N}{r^{n-s}}$$ for every $r>0$ and thus $$|c_n|\leq \lim_{r\to \infty} \frac {N}{r^{n-s}}=0$$. This means that $c_n=0$ for every $n>s$. Hence $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{[s]} c_nz^n$$.

Comment: Cauchy integral formula means, in fact, cauchy inequalities. Right?

Comment: Dont matter for me. You can use all characters:))