# To alternatively prove the theorem(*) by proving that $g^{(n+1)}(z_0)=0$ $\forall z_0\in \Bbb C$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, self-learning

Assume that $g=x+iy$ be an entire function.

**By a theorem(*)**, $\vert x(z)\vert \le N \vert z\vert ^n \ \ \forall z$ large enough and for constant $N\gt 0$ and for non-negative $n\in \Bbb Z$ $\Rightarrow$ $g$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$.

Accourding to the proof (**), $g$ is C-analytic in $D(0,M$), and $M\gt 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $$g(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi}x(Me^{i\theta})\frac{Me^{i\theta}+z}{Me^{i\theta}-z}d\theta +iy(0)$$

Supposing differentiation w.r.t $z$ can be carried inside the integral sign $\forall$ orders, give an alternative proof of theorem(*) by proving that $g^{(n+1)}(z_0)=0$ $\forall z_0\in \Bbb C$

---

I dont really have an idea. Please help me solving this. Thank you lot.

Comment: What is the theorem we're trying to prove?

Comment: An alternative proof for Theorem(*) by showing $g^{(n+1)}(z_0)=0$. @mehta

Comment: What is Theorem (*)?

Comment: @Mehta it's a common variant of Liouville's theorem (presuming OP meant $g$ to be thus bounded).

Comment: I stated dark-writing @mehta

Comment: It's not really possible to prove Theorem * if nobody knows what Theorem * even says...

Comment: @mehta I see this question in an exercise question in notebooks. If you want, I can post it. All question is this. And I asked this to learn for an exam. All I know is this.

Comment: @Mehta it's written right there. Assuming a complete function is bounded by $M|z|^n$ for large enough $z$, prove that it's necessarily a polynomial of degree at most $n$.

Comment: Can you prove this as it is said above? Dear @JonathanY.

Comment: Not quite, and I have to go, so I CW'ed it. Someone could probably dot the i's before I get around to fixing it (but I'll give it a try if nobody does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\frac{d}{dz}\left(x(Me^{i\theta})\frac{Me^{i\theta}+z}{Me^{i\theta}-z}\right) = \frac{2Me^{i\theta}x(Me^{i\theta})}{(Me^{i\theta}-z)^2},$$
so we can deduce that for all $n>1$,
$$\left(x(Me^{i\theta})\frac{Me^{i\theta}+z}{Me^{i\theta}-z}\right)^{(n)} = n!\frac{2Me^{i\theta}x(Me^{i\theta})}{(Me^{i\theta}-z)^{n+1}}.$$
Use the fact that $|x(z)|<|g(z)|<N|z|^n$ for large enough $z$ (and the fact that $g$ is complete) to bound
$$|g^{(n+1)}(z)|\leq |y(0)| + \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}(n+1)!2M\frac{|x(Me^{i\theta})|}{|Me^{i\theta}-z|^{n+2}}d\theta \leq\\
\leq |y(0)| + \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}(n+1)!2M\frac{NM^n}{(M - |z|)^{n+2}}d\theta = |y(0)| + (n+1)!2M\frac{NM^n}{(M - |z|)^{n+2}},$$
and the second term tends to zero as $M\to\infty$, proving at least (by Liouville) that $g^{(n+1)}$ is constant, hence $g$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n+1$. I'm having difficulty right now tightening the bound to show it's actually of degree $n$, so perhaps someone else could carry us home?